# Organize div horizontally

Tags: php, css

My URL: [illandeistudio](http://www.ilandeistudio.com/store/)

If you scroll halfway down you will see a list of categories (Accessories, dinning, lighting...)

They are currently vertical. How can I get these to display horizontally? Optimally they would be 4 per line. Below is the PHP code which places all the "categories" into a div "nelson"

[image: PHP]

Thanks! This has been hell!

Comment: Not for the question, but another bit of advice: I'd suggest looking into an image compressor. The site looks shnazzy, but took a large amount of time to load!

Comment: Please post actual code, rather than an image of your code.

Comment: set your if condition before the foreach to optimize it

Answer (score 2):

```
.nelson {
     float: left;
     padding: 0 3px;
}
```

Then just style the padding from there. You can replace padding: 0 3px; with width: 80px; and adjust it from there if you want the columns to be even (might look better).

If you want it to be centered with 4 columns (you have 7 items so it would be 4 columns, 2 rows, and the last column would only have 1 row).... not sure why you would want it like that but its possible. You would create a  around the code you wrote, create a width, and add the attribute:

```
style="margin: 0 auto; width: 916px;"
```

Then you would adjust the width of that to be the product of 7 * the width of .nelson

I'd recommend just adjusting padding though and leave the menu going horizontally. all the way across for all 7 items.

Comment: great.. do you know if it would be possible to do 2 lines of 4?

Comment: Surround the code you have with: <div style="margin: 0 auto; display:block; width: 916px; overflow: auto;">*CODE HERE*</div>

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. Floats remain mysterious to me and this helped me with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

use  like :

```
<?php if (count($this->document->shoppica_categories_arr) > 0) : ?>
   <ul id="categories">
   <?php $i = 0; ?>
   <?php foreach ($this->document->shoppica_categories_arr as $category): ?>
       <?php $i++ ?>
       <li <?php if ($i % 4 == 0) : ?> class="ln"<?php endif ?>><?php echo $category->getName() ?></li>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

css file :

```
ul#categories li {
   float: left;
}
ul#categories li.ln {
   clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Tallboy said. :) You may also need to set a width for the .nelson divs to get them floating correctly and lining up.